# how to write a batch script to read the content of an xml file which is available in some remote location and based on its value trigger the build

Tags: xml, batch-file, jenkins, xml-parsing

I have an XML file called test.xml which is available @ \mymachine\test. The content looks like below.

```
<root><node1 component="component1" status="ToBeInstalled" />
<node2 component="component2" status="Installed" />
<node3 component="component3" status="ToBeInstalled" /></root>
```

Now I want to write a batch script which will read this test.xml from the path \mymachine\test and trigger a build, if for any component(component1,component2,component3) the status is "ToBeInstalled". I will use "Script Trigger" trigger type to achieve this. But can you please help in writing a batch script ? I am new to batch script.

Answer (score 0):

This little batch file searches for the string **ToBeInstalled** and outputs with command `echo` a line if the string is found anywhere within the file.

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C "ToBeInstalled" \mymachine\test\test.xml >nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo Trigger script as ToBeInstalled is found in XML file.
```

I don't know what is necessary to *trigger script*.

An alternate batch code:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M /C:ToBeInstalled \mymachine\test\test.xml >nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo Trigger script as ToBeInstalled is found in XML file.
```

This code uses **findstr** instead of **find** which is more powerful than **find** and less restrictive on command line syntax.

Run in a command prompt window following commands for additional help:

1. `if /?`
2. `find /?`
3. `findstr /?`

The console applications `find` and `findstr` exit with return code 1 assigned to **errorlevel** if the string could not be found in the file. Otherwise the return code is 0.

`if not errorlevel 1` means NOT GREATER OR EQUAL 1 or in other words SMALLER THAN 1, i.e. is equal 0 as `find` nor `findstr` exit ever with a negative number.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mofi. But when I tried executing the code that you gave, it's returning the output like below. (I removed > nul, so that I can see the count)                                                                                                       ---------- F:\TEST\TEST.XML: 2 (This is correct, as I have 2 nodes having ToBeInstalled )
The syntax of the command is incorrect.                                                        But for if condition it's giving the above message. Even I tried with the code if %errorlevel% == 0 echo Trigger script as ........ but got the same error

Comment: I edited my answer and added an alternate batch code. I can't tell you which error you have made on the line calling __find__ without seeing exactly the line you have used in the batch file. What I have posted works on Windows 7 x64 and XP x86 with a file `test.xml` in a directory `test` being a subdirectory of directory `mymachine` which is a directory in root of current drive.